# System.AddIn (Maf) Interconnection between addins

Tags: c#, .net, aggregation, system.addin, maf

I want to use MAF in my project because I need a robust add-in architecture. Yet I come to a point where I need to call methods of an add-in from an other add-in. How can I achieve this with a flexible manner in which some add-ins should have dependencies over other add-ins or just use other add-ins' functionality when available.

Maybe aggregation via host process?

Thank you in advance for your kind answers.

Ufuk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish / subscribe eventing, using the host process/context as the link.

I don't know MAF, but there must be some generic event you can raise from a plugin A with your custom eventdata to which plugin B can easily subscribe via the host/context.

That would keep it nicely loosely coupled.

Answer (score 1):

I found an example of achieving it.

http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/06/maf-gymnastics-event-hub.html

Thank you for your answer Wim.